# How to delete two or more columns in csv using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file with 4 columns (Name, User_Name, Phone#, Email"). I want to delete those rows which have none value either in Phone# or Email. If there is none value in column (Phone#) and have some value in column(Email)or vise versa I don't want to delete that column. I hope you people will get what I want.
Sorry I don't have the code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "vise versa I don't want to delete that column" here I mean row not column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the pandas `notna()` function to get a boolean series indicating which values are not missing. You can call this on both the email and the phone column and combine it with boolean `|` to get a truth series indicating that at least one of the email and phone columns is not missing. Then, you can use this series as a mask to filter the right rows.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Import .csv file
df = pd.read_csv('mypath/myfile.csv')

# Filter to get rows where columns 'Email' and 'Phone#' are not both None
new_df = df[df['Email'].notna() | df['Phone#'].notna()]

# Write pandas df to disk
new_df.to_csv('mypath/mynewfile.csv', index=False)
```